# How is a complied program updatable?

Tags: c

We all know in the case of web sites, to make update just means opening the code, editing it and saving it. And to view the changes we just have to refresh the browser. 
But what about in the case of compiled programs like a game or other apps or even an OS. How does it work? What happens to the code?

Comment: The (compiled) code gets replaced.

Comment: Just because the code has been compiled doesn't mean the original source code is gone. You can update the original source, compile it to obtain a new compiled executable, which replaces the old one.